# Blazor server side and navigating to controller: Sorry, there's nothing at this address

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I am trying to implement controller to my blazor server application, but runned across interesting problem that I can not handle or find answer:

So situation is this.

First I add controller mapping in my startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers(); <-- this


    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

Next navigation lint to that controller:

```
<button @onclick="DownloadFile">Download</button>
@code{
    private void DownloadFile()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Game/Games", true);
    }
 }
```

and finally adding a simple controller to my blazor app:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class GameController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet, ActionName("Games")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return Ok("Test");
    }
}
```

As you can see it runs as get method, and it this forms it works. But when i change this to  HttpPost

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Games")]
```

I am geting

> Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

I created event clean blazor project with .net hosted option (there is a weather call there using api) and when I change get to post I am getting the same result.

Is this mean that blazor does not support POST?
What am I  missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Navigating to page means executing a HTTP GET request on a specified resource, your browser does this as well, if you give it the address `https://stackoverflow.com/q/70078911/9363973` it will perform a GET request and render the HTML. You cannot POST something by navigating to it

Comment: Ok, i checked quick form with post method and submit and actually this worked :) thank you. Publish this as an answer so I can upvote it :)